# Application running on AVD for API 28 but not API 24

Tags: android, android-studio

My application runs fine in AVD
Just like the image below when running on AVD which has API 28
[image: AVD for API 28 Running Result]

My phone has API 24 which is lesser compared to API 28 it shows this on my phone
[image: it shows up this image on my phone]
same goes to AVD that is also lesser then API 28
[image: same as for AVD which is lesser then API 28]

this is the log when the app is on AVD which has API 24 instead of 28

```
07-05 07:25:16.856 7663-7663/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
07-05 07:25:16.857 7663-7663/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
07-05 07:25:16.985 7663-7663/com.example.rex.quadtrorun W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.rex.quadtrorun-2/lib/x86_64
07-05 07:25:17.130 7663-7663/com.example.rex.quadtrorun W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-05 07:25:17.154 7663-7663/com.example.rex.quadtrorun I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2340)
        at void android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
07-05 07:25:17.155 7663-7663/com.example.rex.quadtrorun I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:605)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:516)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:464)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void com.example.rex.quadtrorun.MainPage.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainPage.java:67)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.rex.quadtrorun-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.rex.quadtrorun-2/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-05 07:25:17.156 7663-7663/com.example.rex.quadtrorun I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2340)
        at void android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:605)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:516)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:464)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void com.example.rex.quadtrorun.MainPage.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainPage.java:67)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
07-05 07:25:17.157 7663-7663/com.example.rex.quadtrorun I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
07-05 07:25:18.974 7663-7722/com.example.rex.quadtrorun I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-05 07:25:18.974 7663-7722/com.example.rex.quadtrorun D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
07-05 07:25:18.975 7663-7722/com.example.rex.quadtrorun W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
07-05 07:25:18.975 7663-7722/com.example.rex.quadtrorun D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
07-05 07:25:19.036 7663-7722/com.example.rex.quadtrorun D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7fb314e40320: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
07-05 07:25:19.103 7663-7722/com.example.rex.quadtrorun D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7fb314e40320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7fb314e0c300)
07-05 07:25:19.186 7663-7663/com.example.rex.quadtrorun D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-05 07:25:19.467 7663-7663/com.example.rex.quadtrorun E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rex.quadtrorun, PID: 7663
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(311498880bytes) bitmap.
        at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
        at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
        at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:17314)
        at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:17250)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17062)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16053)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1966)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17074)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:751)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16053)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:656)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:662)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:770)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2796)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2604)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2211)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

PS: I'm new to this android studio and sorry for any misleading question

**

> Updates

** 
I still don't know how to solve the problem even though there's a solution as I have zero experience in Android Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see from logs

You are using API that is available only from API 28 and above.  [`View.OnUnhandledKeyEventListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnUnhandledKeyEventListener) that has been added in API 28.

That is why it crashes on devices lower than 28. 
You can use

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) {
   // Call your new API method
}
```

For more please have a look at: [Support different platform versions.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms)

Comment: Thanks for the infomation

Comment: So is there a way to just reduce my application to a lower api?

Comment: There is no way to call `API 28` classes/methods in lower `API`. 
Some of the new features are back ported via [*Support libraries*](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/).

Comment: The exception is coming from ViewCompat, therefore it looks like a problem with ViewCompat itself.

Comment: @Mark exaclty. I have this: "at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
2019-01-25 19:41:12.928 24760-24760/com.agilefreaks.szabifreaks I/zygote64:     at void android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)" Still 28 vs 24 issue. Android bugs

Answer (score 4):

I think it has to do with new API 28.

Adding this to build.gradle(Module:app) file helped me in similar issue:

```
android{
    ...
}
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
    DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion "26.+"
        }
    }
  } 
}
dependencies {
...
}
```

taken from [similar exception answer](https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/146)

Comment: where in whicn build.gradle and which part?

Comment: edited, you can probably also put it in android section, I did it this way and it works.

Comment: this is the correct answer. I have tested, it will solve the issue. https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/146

Answer (score 2):

the error message clearly reads:

> Canvas: trying to draw too large(311498880bytes) bitmap.

the accepted answer has nothing to do with that (that log-spam can be considered as "nothing to worry about"). instead the `Bitmap` dimensions should be reduced, in order to fix it properly.