# Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>

Tags: java, android, event-listener

I created a new project with `Empty Acitivity` and I got this error.

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
```

I never had this problem for more than a year. And I tried these and None of them didn't work.:

[How to resolve NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52537638/how-to-resolve-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-landroid-view-viewon)

[Application running on AVD for API 28 but not API 24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185566/application-running-on-avd-for-api-28-but-not-api-24)

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117685087

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same issue and nothing helps...

Comment: @June, I think it was cache problem. Try deleting all the caches and restart Android Studio.

Comment: @June did it work? It'd be great if you can share the solution.